# PDFKit PDFViewAnnotationHit Notification for signature is not working on iOS 11.0 and 11.1

Tags: ios, pdf, notifications, annotations, pdfkit

I'm using PDFKit in an iPad app which shows a PDF document with annotations and want to popup a signing panel for the user to sign the document.

I register the notification using this code:

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(annotationClick(notification:)), name: .PDFViewAnnotationWillHit , object: nil)`

and printout the notification in the callback function

Everything is working until I tested the app on iOS 11.0 and 11.1, which I cannot get the selector function called if the annotation is either Text or Signature (and working on other types). And it works fine on 11.2+

Anyone knows what's going on? Is it a bug associated with PDFKits on iOS 11.0/11.1?

Answer (score 0):

It is working in iOS 12.2 but not in 13 and 13.1 or (13.2 beta)